# Mapping a plus symbol with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use mapplotlib to graph a plus symbol that looks like this:

```
   _
 _| |_
|_   _|
  |_|
```

I've been reading through the matplotlib docs but, frankly, I'm not even sure what to search to fix my problem. Effectively I want to have two points on the same X axis (I.E. a vertical line) but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Ideally I'd like to do this with one set of plot points, though I understand if this isn't possible.

Please let me know if I can clarify my problem in any way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw your desired figure on to graph paper,
2. write down the x,y values of the corners,
3. put those values into a pair of lists, (one for x and one for y), in the same order,
4. plot it.

For example:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> y =[10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10]
>>> x =[10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 20, 10]
>>> line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go-')
>>> ax.grid()
>>> ax.axis('equal')
(0.0, 30.0, 10.0, 40.0)
>>> plt.show()
```

Produces:[image]

Comment: One easy way it's worth mentioning to do #3 is to use `zip(*whatever)`, e.g. `x,y = zip(*vertices)` to unpack `[(1,2),(2,4),(3,6)]` into `(1,2,3)` and `(2,4,6)`.

Comment: I may add that in later, didn't like to complicate things.

Comment: What would the plot code be? I've tried `plt.plot(x, '', y, '')` but that doesn't look right at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have done a little search you should have found a few links how to create custom markers. The best I came up with to answer your question is to use a [Path](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html) object as marker. Therefore you can create a function which creates the desired path (I was to lazy to write the cross so I took a simpler rectangle):

```
def getCustomMarker():
    verts = [(-1, -1), # left, bottom
             (-1, 1), # left, top
             (1, 1), # right, top
             (1, -1), # right, bottom
             (-1, -1)] # ignored

    codes = [matplotlib.path.Path.MOVETO,
             matplotlib.path.Path.LINETO,
             matplotlib.path.Path.LINETO,
             matplotlib.path.Path.LINETO,
             matplotlib.path.Path.CLOSEPOLY]

    path = matplotlib.path.Path(verts, codes)
    return path
```

You are now able to plot any data with the desired custom marker:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

axes.plot(x, y, marker=getCustomMarker(), markerfacecolor='none', markersize=3)

plt.show()
```

This enables you to plot any marker at any position you want it to be at the desired size.

Comment: I'm confused as to how a custom marker of a square solves my problem?